# How to remove duplicates based on column value

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I need to pick a row based on a column value, example:

```
COLUMNID   COLUMN2    COLUMN3   COLUMN4   PRIORITY
  1        value34      null       S        2
  1        value34       5         N        1
  2        value23       5         S        2
```

I need to load the row with the priority 1.

**My distinct is based on all columns but priority.**

**I can not use SQL override**

Answer (score 0):

Use `Aggregator` and group by all the columns except `PRIORITY`, add new output port to calculate `MIN(PRIORITY)`. Done.